# Issue while sending image data to web service in iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, web-services, uiimage, ios9, xcode7

In signup or edit profile, I am sending image to web services to store in server data. It is working fine in iOS 7 and 8 but while using same code in iOS 9, it's not working. I have already updated my code as per ATS rules and all other APIs are working fine.

I am using HTTP Wrapper library for all API. And using Objective C in Xcode 7.

```
          if (filePath!=nil) {

            NSMutableDictionary *imgdic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init ];
            [imgdic setValue:filePath forKey:@"filepath"];
            [dict setValue:imgdic forKey:@"image"];
        }
        [self.postProfileWrapper requestWithMethod:@"POST" url:strUrl param:dict imageName:nil];
```

Here self.postProfileWrapper is object of HTTPWrapper Library

In RequestWithMethod:

```
       if(dictParam != nil)
    {
        NSArray *allKey = [dictParam allKeys];
        for(int i=0; i<[allKey count]; i++)
        {
            NSString *key = [allKey objectAtIndex:i];
            if([key isEqualToString:@"image"])
            {
                NSMutableDictionary *dict = [dictParam valueForKey:key];
                NSString *filepath = [dict valueForKey:@"filepath"];
                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
                [data retain];
                [requestMain setData:data forKey:@"profile"];
                //   [requestMain setPostValue:@"jpeg" forKey:@"type"];
                [requestMain addData:data withFileName:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"imagename"] andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"profile"];
            }
        }
    }
}
[requestMain retain];
[requestMain setDelegate:self];
[requestMain startAsynchronous];
```

requestMain is object of ASIHTTPRequest library.

In iOS 9, server gives error from previous fields (other then images) like first name is missing.

Comment: Update your question with relevant code. Check all results codes/errors and look in the console for anything useful. Provide details in your question.

Comment: @rmaddy i have updated code, please check and give you view. Thanks

Comment: @dk-obl - Did you find solution for this issue? I am also facing same problem.